# Gifs wont appear on website

Tags: html, css

I'm making a small website for one of my classes, I want to put 2 gifs and 2 images in one table 2x2 for some reason they just show up as tiny red boxes, The css on the page creates a red border so I'm assuming all that's showing is the css.

```
<html>

<head>
<title> HYPE! HYPE! HYPE! HYPE! HYPE! HYPE! HYPE! HYPE! HYPE!  </title>
 <meta name="description" content ="Website for the game mirrors edge 2" />
 <meta name="author" content="---" />
 <meta name="copyright" content="&copy;2015" />
 <!-- specify a base formatting style sheet file-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css" />
 <!-- specify a local formatting style sheet for this page-->
 <style>
  body {background-color : light-grey; color : silver;}
 </style>



</head>
<body>
<table>
<caption> Mirrors edge 2 </caption>
<tr>

<td><a href="Home.html"> Home </a></td>
<td><a href="Comments.html">Commments</a></td>
<td><a href="Story.html">Story</a></td>
<td><a href="WWK.html">What we know</a></td>
<td><a href="Hype.html">Hype!</a></td>
<td><a href="list.html">List of Characters</a></td>
<td><a href="Studio.html">The Studio</a></td>
</tr>
</table>

<header> <h2> I can't wait </h2>
<p>It's going to be so good</p>
</header>

<h1> GET STOKED </h1>

<table>
<caption> HYPE </caption>
<tr>
<td><img src"hype1.gif"></img></td>
<td><img src"hype2.gif"></img></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src"faith3.jpg"></img></td>
<td><img src"logo.jpg"></img></td>
</tr>
</table>

<h3> My Sub sub heading </h3>
<br />
my text my text my text
</br>
<a href="Home.html">Return</a>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is the url location correct?

Comment: Under some (many) conditions, If the width/height of the containing element (table cell, div, etc) is insufficient to display the image, the image will not display. In Chrome, right-click on the image and choose *Inspect Element.* Dev Tools will open. In right pane, notice the css for the element you are inspecting. Right click on image and choose "Open link in new tab" -- if tab is blank, url location is wrong. Otherwise, try adding new css statements to very top right box **(`element.style`)**

Comment: This is probably a 404 error. Double-check the file names and paths. Note that `foo.gif` and `foo.GIF`, for example, are not the same.

Comment: @EdCottrell I understood OP description to mean that something on the page had a red border (css), and that (element border) was all that was visible. As it turns out, you were closer to the answer -- see OP's solution posted below ollierexx's answer

Comment: @gibberish Hmmm.... That may be what OP meant. It's not very clear, but I think I misread it. So, fair point.

Answer (score 1):

If they are showing up as error boxes inside the table, the URLs of the images are probably incorrect. Check and ensure the images are correctly named and in the same folder as the HTML file.

Comment: I got it, I forgot to add an equals sign to the <img> tag

Comment: Ahh, missed that. Good luck!